# Tried accessing my custom shared object, but permission is denied

Tags: c#, linux, visual-studio, tizen, nui

Created a basic C++ shared objects file using g++:

```
// calculate.hpp
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C"
{
#endif

  // typedef struct ...;
  // function decls
  int Add(int x, int y);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

with a C++ file that implements the functions:

```
// calculate.cpp    
#include <iostream>
#include "calculate.hpp"
    
int Add(int x, int y) {
    return x + y; 
}
```

and I basically created the shared library via

```
g++ -fPIC -shared calculate.cpp -o calculate.so
```

My C# app on my Linux system can run it flawlessly:

```
// sandbox.cs
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace sandbox;

class Program
{
    // (changed the directory due to privacy stuff)
    [DllImport("/.../shared-objects/calculate/libcalculate.so")]
    static extern int Add(int x, int y);

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int result = Add(15, 20);
        Console.WriteLine($"Result of so is: {result}");
    }
}
```

However, when I try to run it via a Tizen application package (a C# app for the TV) through my Smart TV, this is what I get:

```
System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load shared library '/home/guest/libtest/libcalculate.so' or one of its dependencies. In order to help diagnose loading problems, consider setting the LD_DEBUG environment variable: /home/guest/libtest/libcalculate.so: cannot open shared object file: Permission denied
```

As you can see, I have the .so file in /home/guest/, but I also tested it in other places: /lib/, /opt/data, /home/. Just anywhere I can think of. Still the same exception: permission denied.

I modified the file through chmod too (currently -rwxrwxrwx) and made sure my ls -ld of / /usr and /usr/lib was all good, and still permission denied. Now the question is whether this actually is an access-related issue, or more to do with how app packages are handled on a TV?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Your binary must be built for the armel architecture, not the architecture of your Linux PC (x64). You can cross compile your code by installing `g++-arm-linux-gnueabi` (replace `g++` with `arm-linux-gnueabi-g++` in your build command). You can alternatively use Tizen Studio to create a shared library project but I wouldn't recommend it (because there is no C++ SDK available for the TV profile).
2. You should put the built binary in the right place. Go to your app project directory (where the `.csproj` file exists), create the `lib` directory if it doesn't exist, and copy the `libcalculate.so` file to either `lib/` or `lib/armel/`. Then you can `DllImport("calculate.so")` to load the library in your C# code.

Comment: Would building the .so still be the same? Essentially running `g++ -fPIC -shared calculate.cpp -o calculate.so` ? Or would there be additional parameters needed?

Comment: Oh, nevermind, I see, the new command is: `g++-arm-linux-gnueabi -fPIC -shared calculate.cpp -o calculate.so`

Comment: Just tried it; still getting the same error of:
`Unable to load shared library 'libcalculate.so' or one of its dependencies. In order to help diagnose loading problems, consider setting the LD_DEBUG environment variable: liblibcalculate.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

Comment: Placed the newly generated .so named `libcalculate.so` in /lib/ at my .csproj file

Comment: Are you on physical TV device or TV emulator?

Comment: Both; I'm currently testing on the emulator right now though before I transfer it over to the Tv

Comment: Found the reason: works on the actual TV and not on the emulator as per Samsung's policy [here](https://developer.samsung.com/tizen/Smart-TV/FAQ/FAQ.html). Shared objects importation works (albeit not on emulator). Thanks again!

Comment: If you have any tips on making it work on an emulator (so I can use breakpoints), that'd be swell, though!

Comment: The emulator's architecture is x86, so you have to use `g++-i686-linux-gnu` as the compiler. The lib search path is either `lib/` or `lib/i586/`.